# Setting an IME as the default when it is installed

Tags: android, installation, default, ime

I have developed a keyboard / IME (Cuneiform) and published it in Google Play.  It installs and works fine, but to see and use it a user has to take an extra step to make it their default keyboard.  The process for doing this differs from manufacture to manufacturer and is not always obvious or intuitive.
How do I make setting it as the default part of the install process?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious security and privacy reasons. After all, an input method editor is a very important piece of the user experience, as it has access to all text input, including things like passwords.